# Napili Template Results List component showing now results

Tags: community

We are using the Salesforce Community template Nalili with Winter 16.  The search results component always says no results found.  But when you type your search text in the search the auto-suggest is finding the right articles and you can click on them and view them witht out issue. But if you search for the same term and hit the search button, you always get no results found.

Same issue with opening a case. The auto-suggest doesn't find any articles when it should. Anyone else have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the problem where no results show up after clicking search even when results are displayed in the popup while typing in the search box. I have not found a solution as yet. Update: This link may provide some insight into the problem: https://blogs.perficient.com/salesforce/2015/10/15/topics-in-the-community-builder-napili-template-demystified/